# Are there Smalltalks without Meta-Classes?

Tags: smalltalk, metaclass

At least in Squeak and Pharo, each class comes with its corresponding meta-class, that holds the class-methods of the class. Is this in every Smalltalk the case?

Comment: Just curious - what prompts your question?

Comment: Implementing a Smalltalk-80 descended language.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Wikipedia article on Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk), metaclasses were introduced in Smalltalk-80, and I think all versions now in common use do have them.

Earlier versions, Smalltalk-71, Smalltalk-72 and Smalltalk-76 did not have them.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out a Self language. It is a prototype-based descendant of Smalltalk.

Comment: Yes, while technically true, Self does not have classes either… (at least on the user-level :)

Comment: From the smalltalk Virtual Machine point of view, there is no such thing as metaclass. There are only the classes. I.e. each object has own class, though which are defined its behavior.
As to me, the concept of metaclasses is 'optional' by the means that you can change the smalltalk system to the point, that you will be left only with classes. And this system will still can be fairly called a Smalltalk.